# Android app crashing when trying to call function

Tags: java, php, android

Im trying to load some data from a mysql server using php on a server, and it works, but when im trying to update the data from in the listview, the app crashes.

This is the code that isnt working working, when i remove the downloadJSON from the btn onclicklistener it works perfectly fine, but i really need the update button to work

```js
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        downloadJSON("http://www.cryptocrea.com/test.php");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listView.setAdapter(null);
                downloadJSON("http://www.cryptocrea.com/test.php");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/nWSWXEVJ

Comment: can you past error message.

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(null);` why you setting null  adapter to list?

Comment: I think problem in your adapter class. When you set null in your list view
it may cause of crash.

Comment: As said our friend @Morgan, I think that problem may be the call in the UI thread. Try do call using `AsyncTask`s or some similar to this

Comment: no error in your code just remove ***listView.setAdapter(null);*** this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your adapter `null` on button `onClick()` it makes your adapter `null` after setting list

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
```

Remove it from button click ,here you already setting adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made two mistakes in this code

1. Please place 'asynch' task outside the function and instead of calling the function you can directly call the 'asynch' task.
2. Please don't call UI thread method inside 'doInBackground' method of 'asynch' task, Please call this method from post execute

Answer (score 0):

You need not write below line.

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
```

By setting adapter(null) your adapter is setting null value.
Use set Android Array Adapter Simple item list

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

You can make your code more efficient by Creating constructor in your asynctask in your onCreate() like and onButtonclicklistener

```
 DownloadJSON getJSON = new DownloadJSON(""http://www.cryptocrea.com/test.php"");
        getJSON.execute();
```

Write your code like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
       DownloadJSON getJSON = new         DownloadJSON(""http://www.cryptocrea.com/test.php"");
        getJSON.execute();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

        getJSON.execute();
            }
        });
    }




        class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }



    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] stocks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            stocks[i] = obj.getString("name") + " " + obj.getString("price");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stocks);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```